# Picking 4 items among $n$ items distributed equally into $k$ groups

Tags: probability

Given $n$ items distrubted equally in $k$ groups (each group contains $\frac{n}{k}$ items),
how can I calculate the probability of picking $4$ items all from same group?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Can you answer these questions? 1) How many ways are there to select one group from which you will be choosing the items from? 2) How many ways are there to pick $4$ items out of the single group you chose? 3) How many ways are there to pick $4$ items out of all $n$ items?

Assuming that each outcome (each choice of $4$ items) is equally likely, then if $E$ is the event you are trying to calculate the probability of
$$
P(E) = \big(\text{# ways to select which group} \big) \times \left(\frac{\text{# ways to pick 4 from a single group}}{\text{# ways to pick 4 from all items}} \right) 
$$

Comment: Is it $c(n,k) \times \big(\dfrac{c(k,4)}{c(n,4)}\big)$?

Comment: @cagirici No.  **Hint:** There are $k$ groups, $\frac n k$ items in a single group, and $n$ items in all.

Comment: @cagirici Graham is spot on according to the scenario you described in the problem.